# What’s the difference between applying shape keys and saving shape keys?

Tags: armature, shape-keys

So I understand that once you have a pose, you can apply it as a shape key via the armature modifier. But what’s the difference between saving it and applying it? Is there any special reason one would want to save a shape key?

Answer (score 1):

As explained if you hover over the function, with *Apply*, the modifier is removed, with *Save*, it is kept.

Comment: So is it possible to create a new shape key using the save function? For example, I adjusted my character’s mouth into an “O” after creating the basis key, go into the armature modifier and click “save as shape key” instead of “apply”, if I want to make a new shape key after positioning, can I just readjust the pose and click “save as shape key” to set the new shape key instead of hitting apply?

Comment: yes it looks like it works this way, you can create as many shapekey as you want with Save As Shapekey